# Should i create queries on both window and device code for testing database on window and also run it on real android devices?

Tags: javascript, cordova

i wanna ask if i should make queries on both side. By both side i mean that since i would like to test my database using ionic serve because cordovaSQLite doesn't support on ionic serve right, so it's hard to emulate android device to check my current status. Soon i would like to build it on android devices.So i have to put in this code

```
if(window.cordova){

    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "app.db"}); //device
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST subject (id integer primary key autoincrement, code text, subjectname text)");
}
else{

    db = window.openDatabase("app.db", '1', 'app', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST subject (id integer primary key autoincrement, code text, subjectname text)");

}
```

as my question earlier, i'm curious if i should make 2 queries on both if statement to make it work on both platform or just either one is fine or maybe just insert queries on below of this if statement..

Answer (score 0):

What i have used in my existing application is like

```
 if(DEVICE == ENV_BROWSER){ 
                    db = window.openDatabase("mysql-propcoent", "1.0", "mobile application database", (5 * 1024 * 1024)); 
               }else{ 
                   db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mysql-propcoent"}); 
            }
               db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB);//Ends here
```

Write function for queryDB like

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('query String goes here', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
```

Try follow this approach

In your case also single execute statement will be fine.

Here DEVICE and ENV_BROWSER are constant that have meaning in our application.

querySuccess function be like

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var a =new Array();
    var resultarray=new Array();
    resultarray.push(a);
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var record =new Array();
        var testobj = results.rows.item(i);
        record[0] = results.rows.item(i).column1; 
        record[1] = results.rows.item(i).column2;
        record[3] = results.rows.item(i).column3;
        resultarray.push(record);
    }
}
```

and errorCB be like

```
function errorCB(tx,err) {

       alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
    }
```

Here column1,column2,are select statements outputs column.
Incase of create it will give response and you can then write your function accordingly.
Then try to execute this.Let me know if there are problems

Comment: thanks for reply first of all.. i think this code same like Nic Raboy used. So do we create this queryDB function outside from the if statement or inside them? can you give 1 block of coding please just for example :(

p/s: im new to this android developing

Comment: You have to write this function outside if block like any other functions that you have defined in your code